# How to upgrade iPad simulator to iPad(Retina) simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am using XCode 3.2.5, and I want to run my apps on iPad(Retina) simulator, how can I do this.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install **4.3.1**.  It's in the Mac App Store.  From the simulator, use the hardware menu and select what you want.

UPDATE: 4.3.1 with iOS SDK 5.1 it appears

Comment: I've done this an I only see: iPad, iPhone, iPhone (Retina).  slf, do you have iPad (Retina) as well?  My iOS Simulator is Version 5.0 (272), is yours later?

Comment: @Matthew my iOS Simulator is Version 5.1 (272.21) according to About.  Yes, I have iPad, iPad (Retina), iPhone, iPhone (Retina) under Hardware > Device

Answer (score 0):

I guess this functionality would only available in xcode 4.3.1 ..

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to install the iOS 5.1 SDK to xcode 4.2, which works with Snow Leopard, and you can also include iOS 5.1 for the simulator.

Here are the steps on how to do it: 
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100229-snow-leopard-sdk-5-1-a.html

It is working on my application currently in development but I haven't subitted it to the app store yet.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]